# How to copy a whole row from a Google sheet to another automatically

Tags: google-sheets, move

I have a list in Google Sheets the first column have a value positive or negative .. when I change the value from negative to positive, I want the whole row automatically to be copied to another Google Sheets

Have you any Idea? how could I do this?

Example: the list in a google sheets:

```
Positive NAME1 AAA DDD EEEE CCCC
Negative Name2 AAA DDD EEEE CCCC
Negative Name3 AAA DDD EEEE CCCC
Positive Name4 AAA DDD EEEE CCCC
```

The new list in the new Google Sheet should be so:

```
Positive NAME1 AAA DDD EEEE CCCC
Positive Name4 AAA DDD EEEE CCCC
```

Comment: Creating a filtered list in a new sheet make sense. But do you really want to **move** the row (which includes deleting it from the current sheet)? What if you made a mistake when typing the value, and now the row is gone?

Comment: i edited the title, i just want to copy it to new sheet without deleting it from the current sheet.
I tried to make a filter but it doenst work, have u any idea how could i make its workk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose the first sheet is Sheet1; then on the second sheet, enter the formula

```
=filter(Sheet1!A:F, Sheet1!A:A = "Positive")
```

This will have the desired effect: only the rows with "Positive" in column A will be shown on the second sheet.

You can go further and remove the redundant "positive" column from the second sheet, with

```
=filter(Sheet1!B:F, Sheet1!A:A = "Positive")
```

Comment: Thanks its work now but i want when i change any negativ to positiv to be copied to the bottom of the list, but with this for example when i change the 2. row to positiv it will be cpied to sheet2 in the 2. row but i want it to be copied in the last row 

can u help me to do this?

Comment: I suggest using [timestamp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11458470/automatic-timestamp-when-a-cell-is-filled-out) and sort by it, using [query](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en) for this purpose.

Comment: thanks Max, timestamp works fine, and i sorted it so:
=sort(filter(Sheet1!B:F, Sheet1!A:A = "positiv"); 1 ;True)

and now everythings works super !! thanks you Soup and Max.