# Static TIMESTAMP for Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, scripting, timestamp

In the spreadsheet, need a button that writes the **sheet's timezone** current time and date in a cell, so everytime the button is pressed the timestamp is updated in that specific cell.

After trying different scripts, rejecting some because they don't use the format dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss or do not allow the change of format, reached this point:

```
function TIMESTAMP() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().setValue(new Date());
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var addedDate = sheet.getRange(1,1).getValue();
  var addedTime = Utilities.formatDate(addedDate, SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), "hh:mm a");
}
```

when the button, with the script, is pressed the timestamp with the correct timezone shows in the current active cell BUT an error shows up:

*Exception: The parameters (String,String,String) don't match the method signature for Utilities.formatDate.*

How to designate the cell where the Timestamp should show up, make its values update everytime the button is pressed and solve the parameters error?

Comment: So you want to insert a data and a timestamp? And this in different cells? In which cell do you want to insert the timestamp?

Comment: Wanted to insert it in A1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
function TIMESTAMP() 
  {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
    var addedDateAndTime = Utilities.formatDate(new Date, ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    //Optional if you only want the date: var addedDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date, ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), "dd/MM/yyyy");
    //Optional if you only want the time: var addedTime = Utilities.formatDate(new Date, ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), "hh:mm:ss");
    sheet.getRange(1,1).setValue(addedDateAndTime)
    }
```

Comment: If you use a 24h clock, use "HH:mm:ss", if you use am/pm use "hh:mm:ss a".

Comment: Can you perhaps share a copy of your spreadsheet with us? This should be working so maybe there is something else wrong.

Comment: There was a merged cell so that was the problem. It works perfectly now, thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0):

Looking at you code the cause of the error message is that active cell is not `A1` and that `A1` is blank (as a `getValue` returns and empty string) or has a text value

The solution without changing your code is that before running the function, you click on A1, then run the function.

Your code already is designating the cell to show up the timestamp. On this line

```
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().setValue(new Date());
```

it's using `getActiveRange()`. To use another cell most of the examples that I have seeing use one of `getRange` methods of Class Sheet.

By the way there are a several questions on this site about adding timestamps in Google Sheets. One example is [Automatic timestamp when a cell is filled out](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11458470/1595451)

Reference

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet

Comment: Yes, there are many about automatic Timestamps but I have not the expertize to tinker them into a script assigned to a button or make them static.

Comment: In such case you should ask about how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
function TIMESTAMP() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.getRange(1,1).setValue(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(sheet.getRange(1,1).getValue()), ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

so I found a solution that seems to work on my product worklog:

```
=IF(A6="","",IF(B6<>"",B6,now()))
```

`A6` is where the employee leaves their name, but that could be a checkbox, or any other condition you you might want to satisfy.

`B6` is where the timestamp appears when the `A6` Condition is satisfied.

Comment: `now()` will not give a STATIC timestamp, as OP requested. `now()` value will always change when anything else changes in sheet or on sheet reloads; hence the name NOW. it always shows what is the time NOW.

Answer (score 0):

I use this code for my Timestamp.
Then use the Custom Date and Time at the Format Panel.
I hope this helps.

---

```
function TS() {
  const today = new Date();
  return today;
}
```

[Image for the Custom Date and Time Panel][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/errzV.png

---

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Your answer is not really improving the result of this 2yo old question, could you add some explanation/documentation?