# Google Sheet app script timestamp in a button

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to create a button in google sheet when if pressed it will populate the current cell and the cell to its right with the current date and time the moment the button was pressed, but I am getting this error message when I try to press/run the code.

[image: button error]

and this is my code which I have copied and edited from this post [Static TIMESTAMP for Google Sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61955353/static-timestamp-for-google-sheets)

```
    function TIMESTAMP() 
  {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
    var addedDateAndTime1 = Utilities.formatDate(new Date, 
    ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), "MMMM d, yyyy");
    var addedDateAndTime2 = Utilities.formatDate(new Date, 
    ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), "hh:mm:ss a");
    //Optional if you only want the date: var addedDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date, ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), "dd/MM/yyyy");
    //Optional if you only want the time: var addedTime = Utilities.formatDate(new Date, ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), "hh:mm:ss");
    //sheet.getRange(1,1).setValue(addedDateAndTime)
    sheet.getCurrentCell().offset(0, 0).activate();
    sheet.getActiveRangeList().setValue(addedDateAndTime1);

    sheet.getCurrentCell().offset(0, 1).activate();
    sheet.getActiveRangeList().setValue(addedDateAndTime2);
  };
```

Comment: You forgot to call the constructor `new Date()`

Comment: Can you please further explain?

Comment: Does changing `new Date` to `new Date()` help in your case?

Comment: Sadly no, I still get the same error message after changing new Date to new Date()

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the `Date` constructor to `Utilities.formatDate()` instead of initialising:

```js
var addedDateAndTime1 = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), 
    ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), "MMMM d, yyyy");
var addedDateAndTime2 = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), 
    ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), "hh:mm:ss a");
```

Just need to change the `new Date`s to `new Date()`.

Comment: I have already changed the `new Date`s to `new Date()` , sadly I still get the same error message