# How to make dates auto Populate AND change in Google sheets for each day

Tags: google-apps-script, timestamp

I wanted to know if there's a way to make auto-populate AND change dates for each day.

so for example:

Column A is logging info daily, I want column B to auto-populate with each entry in Column A and at 12AM, I want the date to change to the current date while Column A is still logging.

Is there any if condition I can use for this?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand what you mean. Can you give an example?

Comment: @MikeSteelson Im trying to say that if i enter anything in column A, I want the date to be entered automatically in column B, and on the next day, i want the date to change to the next day as well.

Comment: @AbdulRaffay Use `=IF(A1<>"",Today(),"")`

Comment: @Harun24HR yes, but this will also change the previous day's date. I want to log each day's data with its date, won't Today() change the previous day's dates as well?

Comment: It sounds like you want to timestamp edits on ColumnA. You can refer to the [following question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11464015/6908282)

Comment: @AbdulRaffay Then you need script.

Comment: possible only with script